# Installing Scala using Nix on macOS Sierra

Tags: scala, java-8, nix

I would like to install either OpenJDK 8 or Oracle JDK 8 along with Scala using Nix.

I started by installing the Oracle JDK directly. Then I installed scala via Nix by running `nix-env -i scala`. This completed.

However, running `scalac` fails:

```
% scala
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: scala/tools/nsc/MainGenericRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1070)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:414)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I do have JAVA_HOME set:

```
% echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

To reiterate, I want to install Scala via Nix. I'm like to learn one or more ways to do it. Some notes:

- I'm happy to learn more about how Nix packages work if needed.
- I haven't gotten a clear, authoritative explanation of how to install the JDK via Nix on macOS. This seems to be a key part of the story.

Comment: The error is `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` Which means you're JRE version is probably lower than your SDK version.  You probably have the java 7 JRE installed, I would verify that you have the correct version of that installed. Basically you're trying to run code compiled for java 8 in an older runtime.

Comment: @user1875195 Your assessment seems to be correct; I checked the Nix installed script (a shim) for `scala` and it sets JAVA_HOME to OpenJDK 7. Next, I need to figure out how to tell Nix to install a version 8 JDK or rely on my already-installed JDK. Full answers are welcome (these are just comments, useful for clarifications)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I uninstalled scala with `nix-env --uninstall scala`.

Then I updated my `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` to include:

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: {
    scala = pkgs.scala.override { 
      jre = pkgs.jre8;
    };
  };
}
```

Then I reinstalled scala with `nix-env -i scala`. Presto!

Update 1: Changed `jre = pkgs.openjdk8` to `jre = pkgs.jre8`.

Update 2: I filed an issue with nixpkgs at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/22439

Comment: That you had to override its derivation to install Scala looks like a bug you could report to the nixpkgs GitHub repository.

Comment: @Zimmi48 Good point. Yes, since 2.12, Scala requires a version 8 JRE or JDK (see http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12-roadmap).